# jqxDropDownList set multiple item selected

Tags: jqwidget

we are use below code for multiple item checked from jqxDropdownlist.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < parsedData[0].user.length; i++) {
    window.jQuery('#user').jqxDropDownList('checkItem', parsedData[0].user[i] ); 
   }
```

Could someone help for jqxDropdonwlist dynamically selected multiple value ?

Comment: jqxDropDownList you must check multiple value when check property is true. I don't understand the problem in your code, this code not work or you must find a way to use the checked elements?

Comment: thanks for reply.Yes,you are right.we have set checkbox property true for multiple item selected.like this..$("#user").jqxDropDownList({checkboxes: true, source: userDataAdapter,displayMember: "first_name", autoDropDownHeight: true, valueMember: "id", selectedIndex: 0, width: '200', height: '25', theme: theme });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jqxDropDownList you must check multiple value when check property is true like described here:

[jQWidgets: Properties](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdropdownlist/jquery-dropdownlist-api.htm)